# Repeatable fields across collections in Directus CMS

Tags: next.js, content-management-system, strapi, directus, headless-cms

I'm currently using [Directus CMS](https://directus.io/) as a headless CMS. I've already created a collection which is effectively a single page on the website, a homepage in this case. I've created this page as a singleton object.

What I'm trying to achieve is to create SEO fields for each page on the website. I can manage this by creating a repeater and then creating the relevant SEO fields such as title, description, etc.

The problem is that, this needs to be done for each page on the website and there is no way to duplicate the repeater across collections so each collection involves manually creating SEO fields, even though they are common among all.

Is there a way to create a set of SEO inputs where the fields are the same across all collections but the value is different?

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind:

1. You can duplicate a field by clicking the "..." on the field within Settings > Data Model.

[image]

2. You can also set up a Many-to-One (M2O) relationship that re-uses a global SEO Collection within fields on each of your page collections. You could then use permissions/conditional fields to limit which fields/values are allowed based on the "page" being edited.

[image]

I hope this helps! Let me know if I'm way off here.

Comment: Thanks @ranger, for the first option, it duplicates the fields within the same data model so it wouldn't help me as much since I would need to have the fields in every model created the first time. 

For the second case, I realise that this doesn't entirely work because even if I am able to link the data, I cannot modify it. For instance, If I have 2 pages, Homepage and an about page. The global seo could have a meta title tag that reads "This is homepage" and if I link that with the About page, it would still read as "This is homepage", the user cannot modify that for the about page.

Comment: For the time being, I've resorted to created a global seo singleton object and also creating the exact same replica per page so the goal is mainly to merge the 2 at application level and override the global data with any per page data.